# Difference between Memetic and Cultural algorithms

Tags: optimization, heuristics, evolutionary-computing

What is the difference between a memetic algorithm and a cultural algorithm? I mean they're both evolutionary algorithms where they select a subset of the population to apply some local search logic. And I think that even their metaphor is pretty similar.